# redirect 404 urls with query handling

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404

all queries with `site.com/p/QUERY` are handled, but some users wrongly use `site.com/QUERY` for requests, and they see 404 error page.

how to redirect `site.com/QUERY` to `site.com/p/QUERY` and avoid 404 errors by .htaccess?

not found any solution for this case in htaccess tutorials and questions.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
<Files index.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
# Installation directory
RewriteBase /
# Allow these directories and files to be displayed directly:
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|img|js|css|media)
# Rewrite all other URLs to /p/URL
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /p/$1  [PT,L]
# Rewrite all other URLs to /p/URL or /p/some.html?var=1&var2=2
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /p/$1  [PT,L]
```

Comment: it need some exceptions for index.php, login.php and etc. only queries needed to redirect.

Comment: Only GET queries, you mean? Like `site.com/p/?a=b` and *not* `site.com/p/a/b` ?

Comment: Check received url by exists sections in your Database

Comment: @h2ooooooo queries sometimes inserted directly by url. like this: `site.com/q/TYPED-IN-HERE` - @luther: going to test it.. thanks.